# Rewrite serial port communicationf rom C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port

I want to know if I correctly mapped this C++ code which establishes serial port communication to C#.

```
void some func(...)
{
 *hDev = CreateFile(PortNameUNC, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
      OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if(*hDev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false ;

    DCB *dcb = new DCB ;
    memset(dcb, 0x00, sizeof(DCB)) ;
    dcb->DCBlength       = sizeof(DCB);
    dcb->BaudRate        = BaudRate;
    dcb->Parity          = Parity;
    dcb->StopBits        = StopBits;
    dcb->ByteSize        = ByteSize;
    dcb->fBinary         = TRUE;
    dcb->fDsrSensitivity = 0;
    dcb->fDtrControl     = (DTR ? DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE : DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE) ;
    dcb->fRtsControl     = (RTS ? RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE : RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE) ;
    dcb->fOutxCtsFlow    = (CTS ? 1 : 0) ;
    dcb->fOutxDsrFlow    = (DSR ? 1 : 0) ;
    dcb->fOutX           = (XonnXoff ? 1 : 0) ;
    dcb->fInX            = 0 ;      

    if(!SetCommState(*hDev, dcb)) 
    {
      delete dcb ;
      CloseHandle(*hDev) ;
      *hDev = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ;
      return false;
    }


    if(!SetTimeOut(readTimeOut, ReadIntervalTimeout) || !Reset())   
    {   
      CloseHandle(*hDev) ;
      *hDev = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ;
      return false;
    }
}

bool serial::SetTimeOut(DWORD readTimeOut, DWORD ReadIntervalTimeout)
{
  COMMTIMEOUTS *timeouts = new COMMTIMEOUTS ;
  memset(timeouts, 0, sizeof(COMMTIMEOUTS)) ;
  timeouts->ReadIntervalTimeout          = ReadIntervalTimeout ;
  timeouts->ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier   = 5 ;
  timeouts->ReadTotalTimeoutConstant     = readTimeOut ; //...
  timeouts->WriteTotalTimeoutConstant    = 0 ; //
  timeouts->WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 2*BaudRate/8 ;
  const bool ret = SetCommTimeouts(*hDev, timeouts) != FALSE ;
  delete timeouts ;
  m_currentTimeOut = readTimeOut ;
  return ret ;
}
```

This is my C# mapping:

```
 public SerialPortHASP(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits, bool dtr, bool rts, bool xonxoff)
        {

            m_port = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);

            // Just store parameters user entered
            m_portName = portName;
            m_baudRate = baudRate;
            m_parity = parity;
            m_dataBits = dataBits;
            m_stopBits = stopBits;
            m_xonxoff = xonxoff;
            m_dtr = dtr;
            m_rts = rts;

            // Set XonXoff if set
            if (xonxoff)
                m_port.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;

            // Set DTR/RTS
            m_port.DtrEnable = dtr;
            m_port.RtsEnable = rts;

            m_port.ReadTimeout = 500; // or some other values
            m_port.WriteTimeout = 500;

            // Open the port for communications
            m_port.Open();
        }
```

I will need to implement some other read write operations (according to protocol) till I can test if my mapping is right, so this is why I want to double check if I took correct approach in mapping above code to C#? Or should I take [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?182234-serial-ports-C) route with PInvoke calls? Or still try my current approach? Thanks

PS. Thing is you can see this way I can't replicate all parameters that C++ calls allow one to make

Comment: At least one reason for me to use PInvoke for me was this: `dcb->fOutxDsrFlow`. Unfortunately, `SerialPort` doesn't support this, while many serial devices use `DSR` line to notify host computer, that device is ready to receive data (or device is busy). Most of code looks like equivalent.

Comment: @Dennis: Dennis, yes, but then please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861054/how-do-i-modify-this-dcb-structure-so-that-i-can-use-more-parameters, how can I translate that DCB structure to C#, it is based on some bit flags. I see your point about DSR(might happen I need to enable only DTR and RTS though)

Answer (score 1):

I would add to initialization:

```
m_port.DataReceived += _serial_DataReceived;
```

the event to obtain data from the port. It is need for async working.

And

```
void _serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
   int _len = _serial.BytesToRead;
   byte[] _out = new byte[_len];
   _serial.Read(_out, 0, _len);
 }
```

Comment: Reading I am handling in different functions, I am looping till I ensure I received all data.

Comment: didn't get your comment

Comment: Everything correctly. I'm writing - how I think, and think in Russian :)