# Can I use SerialPort.Write to send byte array

Tags: c#, serial-port

Documentation of `SerialPort` `Write` says that

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters.
>   ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or
>   '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to
>   UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466800/c-sharp-serialport-write-not-sending-all-bytes-when-0xcc-in-array). Does this mean I can't send byte array using `write`?

Comment: Yes you can https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Roy: Yes but that is the doc which says "ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'. " - so this is slightly confusing what is why I asked

Comment: If you keep reading you will see that you can change the encoding.  It is the aptly named Encoding property of the serial port.

Comment: @dbasnett: So if I change encoding to UTF8 I should be able to send byte array?

Comment: @dbasnett: Btw. Do you think this implementation is reasonable: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?182234-serial-ports-C?

Comment: Don't know about that implementation.  The serial port only sends bytes.  The Encoding is a convenience that converts strings to bytes based on the specified Encoding so you can use the string overload of the Write method.  If you want to convert the string to a byte array using one of the System,Text.Encoding methods you can use the Write method that accepts a byte array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters

You're confusing methods, which read/write `string`s or `char`s, with methods, which read/write `bytes`.

E.g., when you'll call this:

`port.Write("абв")`

you'll get "???" (`0x3F` `0x3F` `0x3F`) in the port buffer by default. On the other hand, this call:

```
// this is equivalent of sending "абв" in Windows-1251 encoding
port.Write(new byte[] { 0xE0, 0xE1, 0xE2 }, 0, 3)
```

will write sequence `0xE0` `0xE1` `0xE2` directly, without replacing bytes to `0x3F` value.

**UPD**.

Let's look into source code:

```
public void Write(string text)
{
    // preconditions checks are omitted

    byte[] bytes = this.encoding.GetBytes(text);
    this.internalSerialStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, this.writeTimeout);
}

public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // preconditions checks are omitted

    this.internalSerialStream.Write(buffer, offset, count, this.writeTimeout);
}
```

Do you see the difference?
Method, that accepts `string`, converts strings to a `byte` array, using current encoding for port. Method, that accepts `byte` array, writes it directly to a stream, which is wrapper around native API.

And yes, documentation fools you.

Comment: Yeah but what I cited("ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'") comes from the documentation of Write which takes byte array as parameter - this is why I got confused. So?

Comment: No, it would be a very weird behavior. I'll update answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe you can give me some advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859276/rewrite-serial-port-communicationf-rom-c-to-c-sharp, I can't seem to get proper response on that. Should I try SerialPort or go with PInvoke?

Comment: @user300224: commented linked question, but I think, it will be more useful, if you'll post a specific problem.

Comment: I replied to your comment too, please see that. Yes but I didn't move to the testing part yet. Because there are some read/write methods I need to write. First selecting approach

Comment: @user300224: from my point, you're trying to solve the problem before it has occurred. `SerialPort` isn't optimal, but is easy to use, and rather powerful. Probably, you've got a particular device(s), which uses some protocol(s). Try to use `SerialPort` first instead of trying to write some general-purpose serial communications wrapper.

Comment: I see, I will try with SerialPort now. If I get stuck then look for other solutions right? Which other solution would you recommend? (Device is some HASP indeed)

Comment: @user300224: do you mean HASP tokens/dongles? Actually, I can't understand, why just don't use HASP driver API?

Comment: Yes, I don't have that API I have that project in C++ which I linked in other question. That is the code and it is working with HASPs. And just uses WriteFile function from Windows for writing... is it more clear to you now?

Comment: @user300224: sorry, but I can't help you here. I always used driver API from SDKs.

Comment: Ok anyway I will go with SerialPort, and if that doesn't work see other solution?

Comment: @user300224: yes, I think, this is a way to go now.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
port.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

string testStr = "TEST";

port.Write(testStr);
```

and this

```
byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testStr);

port.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

will result in the same bytes being transmitted.  In the latter one the Encoding of the serial port could be anything.

The serial port encoding only matters **for methods that read or write strings**.

Comment: Yeah but what I cited("ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'") comes from the documentation of Write which takes byte array as parameter - this is why I got confused

Comment: Yes it does and the default for the port is ASCII.  You can change the encoding.